# The easiest way to update package above release RHEL

Tags: rhel, package-management, yum, rpm, kerberos

I have to install the `krb5-devel` package in a version at least 1.12 on a RHEL 6.6. Unfortunately the RHEL 6.6 repositories contains the package in a version 1.10.

What would be the easiest way to update the library? Do you know any external repositories, which covers `krb5` and it's dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

Installing the new devel package will probably try to update `krb5-libs` which has many dependencies and might break the system.

The best way would probably be to update to RHEL7, but I expect that is not an option for you.

Other option would be to install the library and dependencies manually in `/opt` or `/usr/local`. That will not interfere with the OS, but is more work.

Answer (score 0):

If the major of the library does not change, an update to the RHEL7 version might be feasible, but it will pull some more dependencies as mentioned already. You could test that within a clone of the machine where you try to upgrade this. Keep in mind that your support subscription might also be rendered invalid by this - either you run RHEL6.7 or RHEL7, I suppose a mix is not supported by Redhat.

Another option would be to download the src.rpm for krb5, and rebuild it locally - but the same as above applies.

Easiest is probably the installation to an alternate prefix as Popieluch already suggested, as this can be done in parallel to the system version. Just keep in mind that you need to point the applications you want to link against krb5 1.12 explicitly to where you installed krb5 1.12.